# How to set background color for children of column

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, admob

I am trying to implement Admob banner ad in my Flutter app. There is a black line above Admob banner, I could not understand how it happened. I did not set any background.

[image]

Current widget:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tb = context.watch<ThemeBloc>();
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
...
...
...
),
        Container(height: 30, color: Colors.red),
        AdmobBanner(),
      ],
    );
}
```

I want to set background color for column. I added

> backgroundColor:Colors.white

line

But it doesn't work:

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final tb = context.watch<ThemeBloc>();
        return Column(
        backgroundColor:Colors.white,//This line is problematic.
          children: [
            Expanded(
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ),
            Container(height: 30, color: Colors.red),
            AdmobBanner(),
          ],
        );
    }
```

It gives

> The named parameter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined.

error.

How can I solve my problem? What should I do to add background color for column? Will it solve my problem?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Container around Column widget.

```
return Container(color: Colors.white,
child:
Column(
        //backgroundColor:Colors.white,//This line is problematic.
          children: [
            Expanded(
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ),
            Container(height: 30, color: Colors.red),
            AdmobBanner(),
          ],
        ));
```

Comment: i have updated the code with return statement.

Comment: its so hard to guess without more code. can you provide some more code?

Comment: Now, it is working without any problem. Thanks...